# Не работает вывод нескольких постов через get_posts() в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'include' => '111,222,333',
    'post_type' => 'post',
));

foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    get_the_ID()
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

get_the_ID() всегда один и тот же - первый, хотя в массиве $posts 3 нужных поста
Почему не работает?

Comment: Потому что wp_reset_postdata у вас в цикле, а должна быть после него

Comment: Вообще я и так и так пробовал

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В итоге заработало так:

```
...    
foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
  > $pid = $post->ID;
  > get_the_title($pid);
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Попробую как-нибудь вынести wp_reset_postdata(), но с таким положением не работало

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в цилке:

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    the_ID()
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```